# Python - How to find a word in string, then print only x letters afterwards

Tags: javascript, python, json, string

So with following im adding Script from a webpage to a dict:

```
script2 = []
script1 = soup.findAll("script")[2]
script2.append(script1)
print(script2)
```

The output is a wall of text, i only want to extract certain things out of it.

How do I filter after a special string and then only print x letters afterwards? With that i could extract everything I want out of it.

Note: I already tried it with json loads but it doesnt work here strangely (example of the script output: https://pastebin.com/xvzQ456P)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with regex.

```
import re

script2 = ...

special_string = 'xxx'
x_letters_afterwards = 5

result = re.findall(special_string + "(.{" + x_letters_afterwards + "})", script2)

print(result)
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestion that way: https://pastebin.com/Xx4tH2EJ and it only prints "..." which means theres something that breaks it. this is how the script looks like i have in the dict: https://pastebin.com/xvzQ456P